# Is a static object/variable stored on cache/session in a web application on .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, session, web-applications

I'm having some trouble recently.

On a WebForm I declare a static object, like this :

```
public static MyObject myobject=new MyObject();
Response.Write(myobject.Title());
```

now, if I load another page that doesn't contain the declaration of myobject and I do again

```
Response.Write(myobject.Title());
```

I see the previosly result. Is the object stored on session during the navigation due to the static? And it's reckon by the VIEWSTATE? Or what's happening?

Comment: It's stored in your application: server-side, all users.

Comment: @markzzz because it is shared between *all* requests by *all* users. Which is rarely what you want in a web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a static variable. It "lives" alongside the type - so it will be shared by all code accessing the same field via the same type in the same `AppDomain`. It will be lost on `AppDomain` recycle, and won't be shared across multiple servers, etc.

Basically it's not a good idea to use `static` variables in webapps other than occasionally for local caching...

Comment: Uhm...but teorically there is an instance of the same object for each "user"; I mean an user who request a page and instance MyObject will access to it and only it, not to another instance of another User. So what will be the problems?

Comment: Static variables do not belong to instances, they belong to types.  So a user gets an instance of a page, but the server holds the type.  Each instance is going to get the type's static variables, if any.  When the AppDomain recycles, the static variables are reset.

Comment: So, if a UserA hold the static object and save to it (for example) the data Marco, another user (say UserB) can read Marco?

Comment: @markzzz: UserA doesn't "hold" a static object to start with. There's no such *thing* as a "static object". There are just static *fields*, which are associated with the type rather than with any instance of the type. This is unrelated to ASP.NET really - it's core C#.

Answer (score 4):

No it's stored as a static variable in the process, which can be recycled at any point, assuming you use IIS.

In short, try not to use static variables in this situation.

To expand on what is happening.  The static variable is stored in the server's process, which is controlled by IIS.  It just so happens that the process is still alive when you call back onto the server.  IIS can recycle this process at any time.

**Update:** OK more accurately it is per AppDomain, which sits in a process - substitute the word process with AppDomain in my previous paragraphs :-)

Answer (score 2):

Static objects are shared across users. It is not stored in session which is unique to user or view state which is unique to each page.

Read up on [ASP .NET State Management Recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx) to find out which type of state management feature to use for which scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, I tend to take the view that you can declare two separate objects within one class - the dynamic object definition and the static object. Normally, if you are creating these within the same class definition, there is a connection between them, and they work in tandem ( the singleton patten is a prime example ).

What it means is that the object is created based on the dynamic object. There is still a static object unaffected by the creation of the dynamic object(s). Because this can be confusing, you should not combine the two without being careful and understanding the distinction between them.

I realise that this is not a real understanding of what is happening, but it helps me to keep in my head the distinction. Each type has its own use, and should be used appropriately ( I have seen dynamic classes that should have been static, as well as the other way round ).